# How to SUM the total count of instances for a particular unique value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have been struggling and would really appreciate some assistance:

I have two tables cars and rides

```
create table cars
(cars_ID    Int (10),
manuf   varchar (30), 
model varchar (30));

create table rides
(ride_ID    Int (10),
 cars_ID    varchar (30), 
ride_dest varchar (30));

insert into cars (cars_ID, manuf, model) values (1, 'Honda', 'CRV');
insert into cars (cars_ID, manuf, model) values (2, 'Ford', 'Fusion');
insert into cars (cars_ID, manuf, model) values (3, 'Toyota', 'Corolla');
insert into cars (cars_ID, manuf, model) values (4, 'Toyota', 'Camry');
insert into cars (cars_ID, manuf, model) values (5, 'Ford', 'Fusion');
insert into cars (cars_ID, manuf, model) values (6, 'Ford', 'Fusion');
insert into cars (cars_ID, manuf, model) values (7, 'Ford', 'Fusion');
insert into cars (cars_ID, manuf, model) values (8, 'Ford', 'Fusion');
insert into cars (cars_ID, manuf, model) values (9, 'Ford', 'Fusion');


insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (1, 3, 'Boston'); 
insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (2, 5, 'New York'); 
insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (3, 5, 'Washington DC'); 
insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (4, 1, 'California'); 
insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (5, 2, 'Dallas'); 
insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (6, 5, 'Canada');
insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (7, 5, 'Canada');
insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (8, 1, 'Canada');
insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (9, 5, 'Canada');
insert into rides (ride_ID, cars_ID, ride_dest) values (10, 3, 'Canada');
```

Output for Cars: `select * from cars;`

```
cars_ID-manuf-model

1-Honda-CRV
2-Ford-Fusion
3-Toyota-Corolla
4-Toyota-Camry
5-Ford-Fusion
6-Ford-Fusion
7-Ford-Fusion
8-Ford-Fusion
9-Ford-Fusion
```

Output for rides: `select * from rides;`

```
ride_ID-cars_ID-ride_dest

1-3-Boston
2-5-New York
3-5-Washington
4-1-California
5-2-Dallas
6-5-Canada
7-6-Canada
8-7-Canada
9-8-Canada
10-9-Canada
```

I would like to count the number of rides by each car type (combination of car_manuf and car_model) The output should display the sum of rides for each carType and should be sorted from most to fewest number of rides.

**Output should be:**

```
CarType-NumberofRides

Ford-Fusion - 8
Toyota-Corolla - 1
Honda-CRV - 1
Toyota-Camry - 0
```

*mycode: without GROUP BY*

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.manuf, '-', c.model) AS 'CarType',
    (select count(*) from rides r where r.cars_ID = c.cars_ID) AS 'NumberOfRides'
from cars c
order by NumberofRides ASC;
```

*myOutput: without GROUP BY*

```
CarType-NumberOfRides
Toyota-Camry - 0
Toyota-Corolla - 1 
Ford-Fusion - 1
Honda-CRV - 1
```

*mycode: with GROUP BY*

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.manuf, '-', c.model) AS 'CarType',
    (select count(*) from rides r where r.cars_ID = c.cars_ID) AS 'NumberOfRides'
from cars c
GROUP BY CarType
order by NumberofRides ASC;
```

*myOutput: without GROUP BY*

```
CarType-NumberOfRides

Toyota-Camry - 0
Toyota-Corolla - 1 
Ford-Fusion - 1
Ford-Fusion - 1
Ford-Fusion - 1
Honda-CRV - 1
Ford-Fusion - 1
Ford-Fusion - 1
Ford-Fusion - 3
```

This is not the output I am looking for. Instead all CarType should show the total number of rides.

correct output is:

```
CarType-NumberofRides

Ford-Fusion - 8
Toyota-Corolla - 1
Honda-CRV - 1
Toyota-Camry - 0
```

How can I get the right output? Do I have to use SUM, if so how would it be placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, you should join the two tables.

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.manuf, '-', c.model) AS CarType, COUNT(r.ride_ID) AS NumberofRides
FROM cars AS c
LEFT JOIN rides AS r ON r.cars_ID = c.cars_ID
GROUP BY CarType
ORDER BY NumberofRides DESC
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that cars with no rides will be included in the join. The corresponding `ride_ID` in those rows will be `NULL`, and `COUNT(r.ride_ID)` doesn't count null values.

Comment: Barmar - This has been a great learning experience for me. Thank you so much for the assistance. You have been very helpful. Thanks for the explanation of using LEFT JOIN.